# css textarea size

Tags: css

My goal is to have a text area that automatically resizes to whatever horizontal space is available after margins. Basically I am trying to align 160px on the left margin
50px on the right margin and then the textarea fills in the rest. Ive tried auto. I have also tried multiple combinations of positions, displays, nesting divs, and more.
So far I have not been able to set the textarea to automatically fill the left and right space that is available. How can I accomplish this?

edit: it needs to fill the document width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="margin:0 50px 0 160px">
   <textarea style="width:100%">123</textarea>
</div>
```

Here is the code

Comment: Does not work, 100% width always extends past document width: http://screensnapr.com/v/smw9GG.png

Comment: Sorry about that, had my old style left on the textarea, worked like a charm thanks :].

Comment: Try like this: <textarea style="width:200px;">123</textarea>