# How to make textareas auto-resize using just CSS?

Tags: css, textarea, autoresize

I need to make a textarea increase in height as it fills with text. I previously had a JavaScript/JQuery solution for this

```
 function expandingTextBox(e) {
  $(e).css({'height':'80', 'overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
 }
 $('textarea').each(function(){
   expandingTextBox(80);
 }).on('input', function() {
    expandingTextBox(this);
 });
```

And this *almost* served the purpose. Briefly, I have a popup in my web application, and I want to be able to drag objects from elsewhere, and dump them in my popup, creating new textareas that resize to fit their contents. This function only resizes textareas as I type in them.

A colleague thinks I can do this with CSS alone -- no JavaScript or JQuery plugins? Every other solution I've found on the interwebs relies on at least some JQuery plugin (and I can't download new plugins onto my machine at work so easily). Is there a way with just CSS?

I've tried changing textareas to divs, and using the contenteditable attribute. This caused problems elsewhere (but it'd take a long time to explain why).

Thx
-- Gaweyne

EDIT: If it is impossible with pure CSS, I'd accept solutions that use JavaScript or JQuery that I don't need to download additional plugins for.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907220/css-textarea-size

Comment: Note that your `each` method doesn't do anything.  It passes `80` to  `expandingTextBox(e)`, and `$(e)` within the function would return an empty collection.

Comment: Not quite the same question Akul, but thanks. The poster in that thread wants textboxes to expand horizontally. The solution offered him doesn't work, and the second one requires a JQuery plugin which I won't be able to download on my machine. 

But if someone has asked exactly what I'm asking and I've just missed it do tell me.

Comment: Don't think this is possible in CSS alone.  Does your code work for existing `textarea`s, but it doesn't work for dynamic ones?

Comment: @RickHitchcock yes I think you're right. That's the result of me fiddling around with someone else's solution until I could get the textareas to be a min height of 80px. With or without the 80 there - meaningless as it is - the problem still stands. D:

Comment: @RickHitchcock. Yes that's *exactly* the problem. Works for existing textareas, not for dynamically created ones.

Comment: Interesting problem. I tried varying `display`, `height`, `-moz-appearance`, `-moz-binding`, `resize` and lots of other properties, but I can't get the height to budge. What is it about a contenteditable div (or pre) that causes problems?

Comment: @MrLister. The problem with using contenteditable, in my specific case, is that it splits the text typed into the div into spans. This will be problematic for a lot of the code a colleague has written. Basically the text inside the textareas I'll be creating need to be accessed by something else, other functions elsewhere. Splitting the text up into an unknowable number of spans essentially breaks a lot of the code in the application. Maybe I could loop through the divs and loop through the spans inside the divs but... :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to handle dynamically-added elements.
2. Move the CSS to a style sheet.
3. On input, set the height to 80, then set it to the scroll height.

**Snippet**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('<textarea/>').appendTo('body').focus();
});

$(document).on('input', 'textarea', function() {
  $(this).height(80).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add new textarea</button>
<hr>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: I might be able to implement this. I'd show you more of my code but it wouldn't make sense outside the context of the app we're building :s I'll get back to you...

Comment: I did something slightly different because I couldn't implement this exactly. Nonetheless this works perfectly. You win best answer. *tips fedora*.

Answer (score 0):

```
.textarea {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
resize: both;
text-align: left;
min-height: 40px;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 0.5rem !important;
border: 1px solid rgb($lightmain, 0.5) !important;
background-color: white;
&:focus {
    border-color: $lightmain !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px $lightmain 
    !important;
   }
 }
.textarea[contenteditable]:empty::before {
  content: "Placeholder still possible";
  color: gray;
 }
<span class="textarea"  contenteditable></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw9Rj/463/

```
textarea#note {
    width:100%;
    direction:rtl;
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding:15px 15px 30px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #F7E98D;
    font:13px Tahoma, cursive;
    transition:box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    box-shadow:0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;
    background:linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
}
```

Comment: Which of these properties will do what the OP wants, and what are the other properties for?

Comment: What Mr Lister said, doesn't quite do what I was asking for O_o

The textbox in your fiddle doesn't resize as I type. It has a scrollbar. Don't get me wrong it's a pretty textbox but...